# Copy queried attributes of a shapefile to a new shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal

I will detail my problem here.. 
I have a polyline-shapefile, which I have successfully read into python using pyshp module. 
My problem is to save the 2nd node of every line feature into a separate, single point file. I have successfully been able to retrieve the 2nd node, using

for i in range(len(shapRecs)):
        print shapRecs[i].shape.points[p-1]

Now I need to save these to a single separate file. How to write a new shapefile from the results of this loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved while using the pyshp module, along with copyfile for projections and list to input and output each set of coordinates, fields and records...